# Регулярное выражение на проверку ссылки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени! Я не силен в регулрках на js вот пробую проверить ссылку на регулярке сообразил как то так ссылка может быть любая (!) сайт например

```
if(vali.search(/^http://[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]\.me/[^.]/) !== -1) { stav = true; }
```

`vali` - это строка с предположительной ссылкой

но что то тут не работает, подскажите где ошибся? К стати раз у нас сейчас появляются домены на кириллице то как можно еще добавить валидность к кириллице?
Вот так еще попробовал -- тоже не работает:

```
if (vali.search(/^(http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]\/[^.]+/) !== -1) { stav = true; }
```

Comment: И не один отвечающий (как и вопрошающий) не в курсе, что все переходят на `https` :P

Comment: а что в JS нет метода, работающего с url? Какие-нибудь URI методы?

Comment: @Visman верно спасибо. Хотел первым делом это сделать и в итоге забыл

Answer (score 3):

```
var RegExp = /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-]*\.?)*\.{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9-]{2,8}(\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])*)?/;

if(RegExp.test(vali)){ stav = true; }
```

Универсальная регулярка, для любых ссылок.

Comment: Нет. Как минимум по доменам верхнего уровня уже не проходит http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: @sicik_xes на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ не дает валидации((

Comment: извините, увидел немного ошибок было все же. уже исправлено

Comment: Кстати, там вроде у вас в регулярке русские буквы (`а-я`), они к чему?

Comment: Покрывают доменные имена на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

```
^http:\/\/cs[0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]+\.me(\/[^.]*|)$
```

Полагаю, как-то так должно быть у вас.
Работает на таких примерах (поправьте, если я неверно понял вашу задачу):

`http://cs124214.vk.me/123124`

`http://cs124214.vk.me/`

`http://cs01.ae.me/123124f`

`http://cs124214.vk.me`

Ваши ошибки:

1. Неэкранированные слеши после двоеточия
2. Отсутствие + после `[A-z0-9]`
3. Опять же неэкранированный слеш в после `me` и отсутствие звездочки

P.S. обратите внимание, диапазон `[A-z]` включает в себя не только заглавные и строчные буквы алфавита, он так же в себя включает ещё несколько других символов. Если вы хотите только заглавные и строчные буквы алфавита цеплять, то нужно использовать `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Исправляйте некорректное поведение: https://regex101.com/r/uD6gW5/1

Comment: @Visman, у автора на конце после слеша может быть любой символ кроме точки. Поведение корректное.

Comment: Я про домен верхнего уровня говорю.

Comment: @Visman, да, действительно, поправил

Answer (score 1):

Исправил ошибки:

1. Не были экранированы «/»
2. Не правильно были указаны наборы символов — [A-z0-9] изменил на [a-zA-Z0-9]
3. Не было указано что символов может быть много

Получилось:

```
^(http|https):\/\/cs[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.me\/[^.]+
```

Comment: вот так сделал if(vali.search(/^(http|https):\/\/cs[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.me\/[^.]+/) !== -1) { stav = true; } - от такой ссылки http://stackoverflow.com/ не хочет пропускать ее(

Comment: @dantelol Вам нужно проверить на любую ссылку?

Comment: @dantelol если да, то Вам нужно поправить описание вопроса и подробно описать какие ссылки могут быть, какие условия по доменам, поддоменам, зонам, адресам

Answer (score 0):

[->Прекрасная таблица](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html) с генерацией регэкспов на разных ЯП из выпадающего списка по двойному клику прямо на тексте. Разобраться там легко, если что, а потом собрать по кусочкам конкретно необходимое.
Суть важно, что таблица соответствует бумажному стандарту, RFC 3986, формально описывающему, что вообще есть ссылка, раз речь о любой.
Вот сгенерённое на JS:

```
var re_js_rfc3986_URI = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-.]*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}|::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::)|[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]+)\]|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)*|\/(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+(?:\/(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)*)?|(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+(?:\/(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)*|)(?:\?(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)?(?:\#(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)?$/;
```

Comment: Ерунда ваша регулярка -> https://regex101.com/r/fY8sJ1/1